# Работа с объектами в VirtualTreeView

Tags: delphi, классы, объекты

Как правильно заполнять записи с объектами?

Как правильно считывать такие записи в событии **OnGetText**?

Запись для работы с **VST(VirtualStringTree)**

```
type
  PLessonRec = ^TLessonRec;
  TLessonRec = record
    Lesson: TLesson;
end;
```

Описание типа **TLesson**

```
TLesson = class
private
  FId, FIndex: Integer;
  FName: String;
  FExercises: TExercises;
public
  property Id: Integer read FId write FId;
  property Index: Integer read FIndex write FIndex;
  property Name: String read FName write FName;
  property SubItems: TExercises read FExercises write FExercises;
  constructor Create;
end;
```

Описание типа **TExercises**

```
TExercises = class
private
  FExercises: TExercisesItems;
  FCount: Integer;
  function GetItem(AIndex: Integer): TExercise;
  procedure SetItem(AIndex: Integer; AValue: TExercise);
  function GetCount: Integer;
public
  property Items[AIndex: Integer]: TExercise read GetItem write SetItem; default;
  property Count: Integer read GetCount;
  function Add(const AName, AContent: String; AType: TExerciseType): TExercise;
  procedure Clear;
  procedure Delete(Index: Integer);
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;
```

Описание типа **TExercise**

```
TExercise = class
private
  FId, FIndex: Integer;
  FName, FContent: String;
  FType: TExerciseType;
public
  property Id: Integer read FId write FId;
  property Index: Integer read FIndex write FIndex;
  property Name: String read FName write FName;
  property Content: String read FContent write FContent;
  property ExType: TExerciseType read FType write FType;
end;
```

Загрузка данных в запись **LessonRec: PLessonRec**

```
procedure FillTree();
var
  LessonRec: PLessonRec;
  RootNode, ChildNode: PVirtualNode;
  ExerciseIndex: Integer;
begin
  RootNode := VST.AddChild(nil);
  LessonRec := VST.GetNodeData(RootNode);
  LessonRec.Lesson := TLesson.Create();

  { Получаю урок вместе со всеми упражнениями }
  LessonRec.Lesson := objLessons[PreviewIndex];

  for ExerciseIndex := 0 to objLessons[PreviewIndex].SubItems.Count - 1 do // to LessonRec.Lesson.SubItems.Count - 1 do
  begin
    ChildNode := VST.AddChild(RootNode);
    LessonRec := VST.GetNodeData(ChildNode);
    ...
    { Как правильно заполнить запись, которая имеет объект с вложенными объектами? }
  end;
end;
```

Событие **OnGetText**

```
procedure TfrmList.vstLessonGetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType;
  var CellText: WideString);
var
  LessonRec: PLessonRec;
begin
  if Column = 1 then // Column = 0 типа CheckBox
  begin
    LessonRec := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);

    case Sender.GetNodeLevel(Node) of
      0: CellText := LessonRec.Lesson.Name;

      1: CellText := ''; // Как обратиться к данным упражнений?
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Ну наверное же надо либо 1) подвязать к LessonRec упражнения, либо 2) хранить  упражнения в подкаталоге, и просканировать child-елементы на упражнения.

Comment: Вот здесь `LessonRec := Sender.GetNodeData(Node)` я не вижу приведения к типу. По идее в каждой строчке case-а должно быть "своё" приведение к нужному типу (при условиии что на каждой глубине свой тип), либо если не case, то проверять is (Но тогда класс должен наследовать обьект TObject). Я в своё время задавал тип в зависимости от ImageIndex - тогда как бы больше свободы какой обьект куда.

Comment: Тут должно быть написано `var ex:PExercises` и в теле `case 1: ex =  Sender.GetNodeData(Node);`

Comment: Здесь `LessonRec.Lesson := objLessons[PreviewIndex];` я получаю урок вместе со всеми упражнениями в запись. Все упражнения доступны здесь - `LessonRec.Lesson.SubItems`. Как правильно зарегистрировать все упражнения в записи LessonRec, учитывая глубину(упражнения)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При работе с VT record`ы, как дополнительные контейнеры, не нужны, раз все данные уже лежат в объектах (т.е. уже имеют свой контейнер).
Для добавления объекта в VT можно использовать такой код:

```pascal
// лучше, конечно, это сделать методом формы/фрейма, на котором лежит VT
function AddItem(Item: TObject; ParentNode: PVirtualNode = nil): PVirtualNode;
begin
  Result := VT.InsertNode(ParentNode, amAddChildLast, Item);
end;
```

Получение любого объекта из нода:

```pascal
function GetItem(Node: PVirtualNode): TObject;
var
  NodeData: Pointer;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if not Assigned(Node) then
    exit;
  NodeData := VT.GetNodeData(Node);
  if Assigned(NodeData) then
    Result := TObject(NodeData^);
end;
```

И уже потом приводить результат `GetItem` к нужному типу, используя (к примеру) `as` и `is`:

```
myObject := GetItem(Node);
if myObject is TLesson then
  CellText:=TLesson(myObject).Content;
```

P.S. не забудьте, что если VT выступает основным хранилищем данных (а я не вижу причин, зачем нужно хранить данные в VT и еще в каком-нибудь списке), то во избежание утечек памяти нужно задействовать VT.OnFreeNode:

```pascal
procedure TSomeForm.vtFreeNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode);
begin
  GetItem(Node).Free;
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я сделал как написано в этом посте [VirtualStringTree - Correct way to add/handle subnodes/childnodes when using objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005452/virtualstringtree-correct-way-to-add-handle-subnodes-childnodes-when-using-obj) Получается данные не дублируются и не хранятся в VT - считываем когда нужно из объектов. Но если аранжировать ноды или сортировать, то Node.Index будет ссылаться на неверную информацию. В Вашем способе такой изъян отсутствует?

Comment: Да. Лучше ориентироваться на сами объекты, чем на их индексы. И если предполагается миксование элементов - то лучше, чтобы контейнер был один, а именно - VT. В приведенном вами примере с большого SO помимо сортировки нодов в VT требуется аналогичная сортировка и внешнего списка. В моем примере - только сортировка VT, а данные уже привязаны к нодам. Поэтому внешний список не нужен и даже излишен.

Comment: Отличная новость для меня. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: Где можно почитать документацию по VST на русском?

Comment: @Fasta http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/topic-118457.html
Файл внизу первого сообщения.

Comment: Благодарю. На досуге почитаю.